# Storing Azure Vault Client ID and Client Secret

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-keyvault, .net-core-2.0

I am using .NET Core 2.0 and ASP.NET Core 2.0 for application development. The "test" application is a .NET Core Console application. The core code I am writing is a class library. Once proper testing. I choose to do this since I won't be putting this to use for awhile (it's replacing older ASPNET code).

Anyway, since I have to work with a LOT of API keys for various services I decided to use Microsoft Azure Key Vault for storing the keys. I have this all setup and understand how this works. The test application uses a test Azure account so it's not critical. And since this is replacing legacy code and it's in the infancy, I am the sole developer.

Basically, I'm running into this issue. There's not too much information on Azure Key Vault from what I can see. A lot of examples are storing the **Client ID and Secret** in a **plain text** json file (for example: https://www.humankode.com/asp-net-core/how-to-store-secrets-in-azure-key-vault-using-net-core). I really don't understand how this can be secure. If someone were to get those keys they could easily access stored information Azure, right?

The Microsoft MSDN has a powershell command that grants access (I lost the original link, this is closest I can find: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/platform-as-a-service/setting-up-and-configuring-an-azure-key-vault/)  My development operating system is Windows 10 and my primary server operating system is Debian.

How would I approach this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you are right, the plain text config file could be used only during development, not for production purpose. And in general, available options depend on where and how you host an App.

If you have an Azure Web App, you have at least next built-in options ([from the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-use-from-web-application)):

> - add the ClientId and ClientSecret values for the AppSettings in the Azure portal. By doing this, the actual values will not be in the web.config but protected via the Portal where you have separate access control capabilities. These values will be substituted for the values that you entered in your web.config. Make sure that the names are the same.
> - authenticate an Azure AD application is by using a Client ID and a Certificate instead of a Client ID and Client Secret. Following are the steps to use a Certificate in an Azure Web App:
>
>   - Get or Create a Certificate
>   - Associate the Certificate with an Azure AD application
>   - Add code to your Web App to use the Certificate
>   - Add a Certificate to your Web App

---

You may also find an approach that uses env variables to store credentials. This may be OK only if you can guarantee that it's not possible to do a snapshot of env variable on prod machine. Look into [Environment Variables Considered Harmful for Your Secrets](http://movingfast.io/articles/environment-variables-considered-harmful) for more details.

---

And the last one thing: there is also a technic that based on the idea, that you need to store/pass only a ClientSecret value while ClientId should be constructed based on machine/container details where the App is hosted (e.g. docker container id). I have found an example for Hashicorp Vault and an App hosted on AWS, but the general idea is the same: [Secret management with Vault](http://chairnerd.seatgeek.com/secret-management-with-vault/)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the first answer, with the context of running applications on Azure VM, instead of using `client_secret` to authenticate, you can use client certificate authentication as explained in this [documentation: Authenticate with a Certificate instead of a Client Secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-use-from-web-application#authenticate-with-a-certificate-instead-of-a-client-secret).

[image: Key Vault Client Certificate Authentication Image]

In the picture above:

- Application is authenticating to AAD by proving that it has the private key of the certificate (which is basically stored in [CNG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204778(v=vs.85).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) if you are using Windows).
- Application get back the `access_token` and then use it to access the Key Vault.

The developer does not need to know the private key value of the certificate in order for their app to be successfully authenticated. Instead, they only need to know the location of the imported `pfx` (a container for private key and its certificate) in the Certificate Store.

At least on Windows, you as secret administrator can convert the private key and the certificate into `pfx` format which is **password** protected, and then deploy it into the Windows Certificate store. This way no one could know the private key unless they know the **password** of the `pfx` file.

---

The other approach specifics for Azure Compute, is to use [Azure Managed Service Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-service-identity/overview). Using Azure MSI, Azure will automatically assign your resources such as VM with an identity / Service Principal, and you can fire requests at a specific endpoint that are only accessible by your resource to get the `access_token`. But be wary that Azure MSI are still under public preview, so please review the known issues before using it.

[image: Azure Managed Service Identity Image]

The picture above explain how Azure Resource Manager assign a Service Principal identity to your VM.

- When you enable MSI in a VM, Azure will create a service principal in your AAD.
- Azure will then deploy a new MSI VM extension to your VM. This provides an endpoint at http://localhost:50432/oauth2/token to be used to get the `access_token` for the service principal.
- You can then use the `access_token` to access the resources such as Key Vault which authorize the service principal access.